# make Langchain Chatbot access multiple knowledge sources

Tags: chatbot, langchain

I am building a Chatbot using langchain I want the chatbot to have a knowledgebase in a vectorstore and also have access to wikipedia. I have created the part where chatbot has a vectorstore to get data from. Please guide me on how can I go about building the feature where chatbot can access wikipedia.

```
def get_answer(query):
    client = get_weaviate_client()
    db = Weaviate(client=client, index_name=INDEX_NAME, text_key="text")
    llm = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0)
    
    chain = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
        retriever=db.as_retriever(),
        llm=llm, chain_type="stuff",
        memory=ConversationBufferWindowMemory(k=3)
    )
    response = chain(
        {"query": query},
        return_only_outputs=True,
    )
    return response['result']
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pip install wikipedia

```
 pip install wikipedia
```

Code sample to make call to API

```
 from langchain.tools import WikipediaQueryRun
 from langchain.utilities import WikipediaAPIWrapper

 wikipedia = WikipediaQueryRun(api_wrapper=WikipediaAPIWrapper())
 print(wikipedia.run("HUNTER X HUNTER"))
```